# Node.js Error Handling -- how to deal with undefined values causing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, xml-parsing, express

Take this URL for instance: **https://api.eveonline.com/eve/CharacterID.xml.aspx?names=Khan**

Using **[xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js)** node.js module you may parse that XML, although it does not look pretty:

```
var CharacterID = response.eveapi.result[0].rowset[0].row[0].$.characterID;
```

The app crashed after 2 weeks of running, all because **rowset[0]** was undefined. Prior to that it crashed because **eveapi** was not defined. Seriously, does my *if-else* has to be like this just to prevent server from crashing due to stupid *undefined* object errors?

```
 if (!response.eveapi || 
     !response.eveapi.result[0] || 
     !response.eveapi.result[0].rowset[0] || 
     !response.eveapi.result[0].rowset[0].row[0]) {
            return res.send(500, "Error");
```

Besides the obvious `if (err) return res.send(500, "Error");` error handling where applicable, what is the general practice for *undefined* errors?

Comment: If you learn what the response is, you shouldn't have this problem. You could always create a function that accepts any number of arguments that looks through an object, basically doing what your `if` statement is, so you don't have to rewrite that long if statement

Comment: @Ian since [] can be used to dereference either objects or arrays, that's certainly possible.  I think most people just aren't that used to variable argument functions, so if Twilight wants to see that answer maybe you could write an example?

Comment: @Paul I don't know if it's a good example, or how universally it can be used, but here's what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/dqUng/ . Hopefully it helps the OP in some way

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought you were doing.  Still needs to be called within a try/catch to branch off and return error responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, undefined is not itself an error, but using undefined as an array/object is an error.

```
x = {'a': { 'b': { 'c': { 'd': [1,2,3,4,5]} } } } ;
try { j = x.a.b.c.e[3] } catch(e) { console.log(e); }
```

prints

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined]
```

This suggests to me that try/catch can be used with your code to return an error code, and if desired, an error text (or just stick the error text in console.log, a database or local file).

In your case, that could look like:

```
var CharacterID; // can't define it yet

try {
  CharacterID = response.eveapi.result[0].rowset[0].row[0].$.characterID;
} catch(e) {
// send description on the line with error
  return res.send(500, "Error: NodeJS assigning CharacterID: "+e); 
// return res.send(500, "error");  use this one if you dont want to reveal reason for errors
}

// code here can assume CharacterID evaluated.  It might still be undefined, though.
```

Comment: you can end up writing hundreds of try/catch.. isn't there a best solution to catch ALL the problems which might arise and handle them in some way or another? I read something about using `Domains` but I didn't understand how it works.

Comment: try/catch can be used within a function for providing a common operation.  No one is forced to duplicate hundreds of try/catch.  Only write a new one if the error handling needs to be different somehow.

Comment: what do you mean? in order to protect each part of the code, which consists of many many functions, one would need to wrap each content of a function with a try/catch, since any part is at risk of breaking

Comment: One try/catch can cover multiple statements, but then it will abandon the statements after the error occurred and jump to the catch.  If you have a series of functions and want to apply common error handling across the series, the functions could be embedded in an array and the array looped with a try/catch in the inner loop to divert errors to an error handler.  But the whole point of exceptions is an admission that there is no best solution to all the problems that might arise and some might be severe enough to stop and just print an error, which is the easiest try/catch use case.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a library for this kind of thing, called dotty (https://github.com/deoxxa/dotty).

In your case, you could do this:

```
var dotty = require("dotty");

var CharacterID = dotty.get(response, "eveapi.result.0.rowset.0.row.0.$.characterID");
```

In the case of the path not being resolvable, it'll just return undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function helps?

```
function tryPath(obj, path) {
    path = path.split(/[.,]/);
    while (path.length && obj) {
        obj = obj[path.shift()];
    }
    return obj || null;
}
```

For your code you'd use:

```
if (tryPath(response,'eveapi.result.0.rows.0.row.0') === null) {
  return res.send(500, "Error");
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/FSazh/) example
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/FqZpP/) same example, but as extension to `Object.prototype`